# how to combine all results from all joined tables into one json output

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I'm joining some tables, using `FOR JSON PATH` for output, but I just want to observe data from all the tables in some structured manner.

```sql
SELECT 
tableOne.attrA AS 'tableOne.attrA',
tableOne.attrB AS 'tableOne.attrB',
...
tableTwo.attrB AS 'tableTwo.attrB'
...
FROM tableOne
JOIN tableTwo 
  ON tableOne.fId = tableTwo.id
FOR JSON PATH
```

And get output like:

```json
{
   "tableOne": {
         "attrA": "asdf"
    }
   "tableOne": {
         "attrB": "fdsa"
    }
}
```

I would like to have somethign for all the values like:

```sql
SELECT 
tableOne.* AS 'tableOne.*',
tableTwo.* AS 'tableTwo.*',
tableThree.* AS 'tableThree.*
....
FOR JSON PATH;
```

I saw `JSON_ARRAY` which can be combined with `JSON_OBJECT` but it's only in SQL Server 2022. I have 2019 version.

Comment: So what are your expected results here, exactly?

Comment: Upgrade to SQL Server 2022 is probably the easiest thing to do.

Comment: Upgrade to a pre-release version? Really?

Comment: I expect this, without necessary writing of all the elements. SELECT 
tableOne.* AS 'tableOne.*', .. but it doesn't work. I realised that FOR JSON AUTO can include all the tables just by doing `SELECT *` so I guess I'll go with that, but every next table is included in previous json hierarchy and you cannot change this encapuslation, but okay.

Comment: I cannot do upgrade, so not yet.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution:

```sql
SELECT 
json_query((
        select t1.* 
        for json path,
        without_array_wrapper -- if its only one match
        ,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES -- if we want to see null values
        )) as tableOne,
json_query((
        select t2.* 
        for json path,
        without_array_wrapper -- if its only one match
        )) as tableTwo
...
FROM tableOne t1
JOIN tableTwo t2
  ON t1.fId = t2.id
FOR JSON PATH, -- needs to be PATH; AUTO returns hierarchy which is just cascading encapsulation
INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES -- just for the sake of seeing all null values
```

And this outputs all the data in formated JSON. I would add some links to ms docu, but later.